# Calling moveItem in the Artifactory REST API results in lock-errors

Tags: python, artifactory, conan

I'm working on a Python script to move packages automatically from one Conan remote to another. Both remotes are hosted within the same Artifactory Pro server. In order to do this efficiently I'd like to use the [Artifactory REST API - moveItem](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-MoveItem). As this is a Python script I use the [module rtpy](https://rtpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html#move-item) for that.

The script tries to move several thousand packages, and mostly it works fine. In <10% of the cases though I get an error from the API. What makes this a serious problem is that binaries get lost - they are already removed from the source, but do not get added to the target remote. This only caused damage on a bunch of test artifacts, I hope nobody else had this issue in a production environment.

The rtpy error is as follows (removed specific package and remote names):

```
Exception while moving artifact [PACKAGE] ([PACKAGE-REF])
Exception was The json output for the error was malformed (Not a standard Artifactory REST API error json), set the "raw_response" setting to True in your settings dictionary to get a raw requests.Response() object for debugging!, requests.Response.text : {
  "messages" : [ {
    "level" : "ERROR",
    "message" : "Failed to move from src=[SOURCE-PACKAGE] to target=[TARGET_PACKAGE]: Lock on LockEntryId [FILE-FROM-PACKAGE-ON-TARGET-REMOTE] not acquired in 120 seconds. Lock info: org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.provider.JVMLockWrapper@71934dd7."
  } ]
}
```

Is it possible that multiple `moveItem` commands shortly after another can lead to these issues? What can I do to avoid this? Has someone else tried something similar?